# Auto updating a php image every x seconds

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

So I have div which contains a php as body background.
Let's say it's image.php

image.php display's a different image depending on the hour/day/month

Now if my website remains open for more than an hour the same image is still displayed which is.. well not how it should be.

However displaying the image works, It doesn't update and frankly, I don't quite know how to approach this.

So here I'm not asking for someone to make this script for me, but rather point me in the correct direction to have a script that reloads the php file completely.

Thank you in advance!

EDIT: Sorry for making it unclear, I really need only the specified div bg to completely reload, not the entire webpage. That's where I get stuck on creating this.

I know how to update an image but as far as I know, that image is already loaded on entering the website so it won't update furtheron, Reloading the entire page is also no-go since the image is placed in the header, and the header is not updating on page navigation since it contains an audio player

Answer (score 0):

Add the following in the `<head>` section of your page:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3600">
```

This will refresh the page after 3600 seconds, or one hour.

Alternatively you can do the same with Javascript:

```
setTimeout(function() {window.location.reload()}, 3600*1000);
```

This will reload after 3600*1000 milliseconds, which is also one hour.

Or you can only reload the image itself, by modifying its `src` attribute. You need to bypass browser cache for this, which is usually done by adding a 'cachebust' GET variable based on the current Unix timestamp:

```
document.getElementById('myimage').src = '/path/to/image.php?cachebust=' + Date.now();
```

Combining the second and third approach yields:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById('myimage').src = '/path/to/image.php?cachebust=' + Date.now();
}, 300*1000);
```

This will reload only the specified image every 5 minutes.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the right approach for me, I'm running a website with an audioplayer in the header. on page navigation everything under the header will be refreshed/navigated with ajax, the head won't update. So I really need the exact div to be refreshed preferably every hour :) But thank you for the advice!

Comment: See the last one, it works without reloading the entire page. Note that you cannot 'refresh a div', that would require a more complex Ajax approach. Reloading only the image is trivial though with the cachebust approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **Ajax Polling**. Here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11988492/3190165) of answer which explain it. You can do it following way:

1. Create an ajax poll function with time period t.
2. Send this Ajax call to a php file that will generate a link for your `#bg` element.
3. Update your image after the success of this ajax call.